# Meteor Как запустить на хостинге

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

Никак не могу перенести метеор. Кучу ошибок и всегда разные. Мне кажется очень кучу способов перепробовал может, кто-нибудь посоветует, что да как. Пробовал demeteorizer, meteor up. Всё бесполезно. Помогите пж. Подскажите где кака и вообще реально ли ?
Подскажите как его правильно запустить . Так как при команде `meteor` всё запускается только на localhost. Как я прочитал метеор приложение нужно переделывать под node js , но все пакеты которые это делают обновлялись 2 - 3 года назад и статей свежих совсем нет . Как правильно это сделать и реально ли ?

Когда я пробую mup setup

```
     Started TaskList: Setup Docker
[37.46.128.131] - Setup Docker
[37.46.128.131] - Setup Docker: SUCCESS

Started TaskList: Setup Meteor
[37.46.128.131] - Setup Environment
[37.46.128.131] - Setup Environment: SUCCESS

Started TaskList: Setup Mongo
[37.46.128.131] - Setup Environment
[37.46.128.131] - Setup Environment: SUCCESS
[37.46.128.131] - Copying mongodb.conf
[37.46.128.131] - Copying mongodb.conf: SUCCESS

Started TaskList: Start Mongo
[37.46.128.131] - Start Mongo
[37.46.128.131] x Start Mongo: FAILED

          ------------------------------------STDERR------------------------------------
          Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

          ------------------------------------STDOUT------------------------------------
```

Comment: Вы можете привести в пример ваш конфиг и ошибки, которые выдает?

Comment: Можете глянуть , только что обновил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Покажу на примере как я вручную заливал на продакшн. На продакшне использовал [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) для запуска сайта.

1. Нужно на локалхосте сначала собрать проект командой meteor build ../
2. Заливаем тарбал на хостинг
3. Извлекаем архив на директорий `tar xzf /path/to/fodler/my-meteor-project.tar.gz`
4. `cd /path/to/fodler/my-meteor-project/bundle/programs/server && npm install`
5. `cd  /path/to/fodler/my-meteor-project/bundle/programs/server/ && export PORT=8001 &&` `export MONGO_URL=mongodb://dbuser:dbpassword@localhost:27000/mydb && export` `ROOT_URL=https://mysite.com && export HTTP_FORWARDED_COUNT=1;`
6. `forever start /path/to/fodler/my-meteor-project/bundle/main.js; exit`
7. nginx проксирует 80 порт на 8001, это вы сами должны настроить или можно просто открыть по порту mysite.com:8001